# How to segment a large HTML page into several small HTML pages to show in the mobile browser?

Tags: android, html, css, mobile

I am trying to segment a lengthy HTML file with lot of UI controls such as textbox, label, button, combobox in to multiple small HTML pages in order to . I tried to find an algorithm to do so. How can I do that?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with jQuery Mobile? http://jquerymobile.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my blog post here http://www.glcreations.co.uk/2011/08/19/cool-jquery-tabbed-content-switcher/

Making tabbed content. Tested and working on most mobile operating browsers (android, blackberry, iphone)

Tabbed content is a great way to get alot of content into a small area :)